# sql query to replace a blank cell with any text in access 2007 column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an access table which has some cells as blank ( no data ) in a particular column.

how i write an sql query to replace a blank cell with any text in access 2007 column

any help appreciated.

i have already tried the sql query

```
update tableA set colA = 'abc' where ISNULL(colA);
```

It updates 0 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Update Table
Set [ColumnName] = "my random text"
Where Len([ColumnName]) = 0 OR [ColumnName] Is Null
```

This will account for situations where the cell value is an empty string or if it is null. If you are trying update one column from another you can do:

```
Update Table
Set [ColumnName] = [MyOtherColumnName]
Where Len([ColumnName]) = 0 OR [ColumnName] Is Null
```

Comment: It is unusual but possible to have empty strings in a column, so you will need, say, Trim([ColumnName])="", if spaces are to be replaced, which means you could have, Where Trim([ColumnName] & "")="", which would get rid of OR.

Comment: Or in Access lingo you can use Nz which is faster than the concatenation: Where Len(Trim(Nz([ColumnName],""))) > 0. Not that it makes much difference. Once you decide to put a function in the where clause you have somewhat accepted that speed isn't the overriding issue.

Comment: Just to follow on all of this, if you've got Allow ZLS turned on (as is the default starting with A2003, unfortunately), it should be turned off. This is a great annoyance to me, since it's such an awful idea. It even gets changed for some converted databases (A97 to A2003, for instance).

Comment: @David-W-Fenton - OMG, yes the ZLS option was and is one of the many evil options in Access. The only thing I assume with Access is that I cannot make many assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure its

```
update tableA set colA='abc' where colA is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
update tableA set colA = 'abc' where colA IS NULL;
```